Could anybody optimize class design and fix issue "mutable more than once at a time" without using refcell in rust?
Could anybody please help on bellow design?

How does a struct member reference to parent struct?
How to fix the issue "mutable more than once at a time" ?

There's a MsgReceiver  to receive messages from network. It has a helper class reader to read all messages. The reader has a callback dispatcher function to dispatch messages. in one implementation of MsgReceiver, it also implements the dispatcher trait.
trait MsgReceiver {
    fn try_recv(&mut self, sock:&mut std::net::TcpStream) -> bool;
}
trait MsgDispatcher {
    fn dispatch_one(&mut self, msg: &mut [u8]);
}
struct MsgReader {
    buf: Vec<u8>,
    // add a member to reference to owner MsgDispatcher???
}
impl MsgReader {
    fn read_all(&mut self, sock:&mut std::net::TcpStream, dispatcher: &mut impl MsgDispatcher) {
        // TODO read all messages until WOULDBLOCK
        // dispatch messages one by one
        dispatcher.dispatch_one(&mut self.buf[..]);
    }
}

// one implementation of MsgReceiver
struct MyMsgReceiver {
    reader:  MsgReader,
    count: usize,
}

impl MsgDispatcher for MyMsgReceiver {
    fn dispatch_one(&mut self, _msg: &mut [u8]) {
        // TODO
        self.count += 1;
    }
}
impl MsgReceiver for MyMsgReceiver {
    fn try_recv(&mut self, sock:&mut std::net::TcpStream) -> bool {
        // TODO: prepare
        (self.reader).read_all(sock, self);  // HELP??? ERROR: cannot borrow `self.reader` as mutable more than once at a time
        // TODO: close if error or user requested.
        false
    }
}


--------------- Figured out a better design -----------------
trait MsgReceiver {
    fn dispatch_one(&mut self, msg: &mut [u8], sock:&mut StreamSock);
    fn on_readable(&mut self, reader: &mut MsgReader, sock:&mut StreamSock) -> bool
            // where Self: Sized 
    {
        println!("Default on_readable impl");
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; 128];
        // TODO: prepare
        reader.read_all(sock, self);
        // TODO: close if error or user requested.
        // self.dispatch_one(&mut buf, sock);
        false
    }
}

struct StreamSock{}
struct MsgReader {
    buf: Vec<u8>,
}
impl MsgReader {
    fn read_all(&mut self, sock:&mut StreamSock, dispatcher: &mut (impl MsgReceiver+?Sized)) {
        // TODO read all messages until WOULDBLOCK
        // dispatch messages one by one
        dispatcher.dispatch_one(&mut self.buf[..], sock);
    }
}

// one implementation of MsgReceiver
struct MyMsgReceiver {
    count: usize,
}

impl MsgReceiver for MyMsgReceiver {
    fn dispatch_one(&mut self, _msg: &mut [u8], _sock:&mut StreamSock) {
        println!("MyMsgReceiver::dispatch_one");
        self.count += 1;
    }
    //-- Below implementation overrides default one -----
    // fn on_readable(&mut self, reader: &mut MsgReader, sock:&mut StreamSock) -> bool
    //         // where Self: Sized 
    // {
    //     println!("MyMsgReceiver on_readable impl");
    //     let mut buf = vec![0u8; 128];
    //     // TODO: prepare
    //     reader.read_all(sock, self);
    //     // TODO: close if error or user requested.
    //     // self.dispatch_one(&mut buf, sock);
    //     false
    // }
}

struct MsgRecvWrap {
    reader: MsgReader,
    receiver: Box<dyn MsgReceiver>,
}
impl MsgRecvWrap {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { reader: MsgReader{buf: Vec::new()}, receiver: Box::new(MyMsgReceiver{count:0}) }
    }
}

fn test() {
    let mut receivers: Vec<MsgRecvWrap> = Vec::new();
    let mut sock = StreamSock{};
    receivers.push(MsgRecvWrap::new());
    let ref mut w = receivers[0];
    w.receiver.on_readable(&mut w.reader, &mut sock);
}
pub fn main() {
    test()
}


Please only ask a single question per post.
